# fill empty vector by matching index and year in R

Tags: r

I want to fill empty vector by matching year with index.
For example, say I am analyzing 18 years of data.
I have a vector consisting of dates in %Y-%m format for eg.

```
vt = c("2004-02","2006-03","2007-07")
```

I have a vector with NA say

```
vv = rep(NA, 18)
```

now I want to fill the empty vector in a way that `"2004-02"` goes to `4th` position, `"2006-03"` goes to `6th` position, and `"2007-07"` goes to `7th` position in the empty vector. I want to fill the empty vector by matching the position with the year.

I can do it by looping over the date vector but I want a vectorize way to do this.

expected output

```
NA NA NA 2004-02 NA 2006-03 2007-07 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: does `vt[order(vt)]` do what you want?

Comment: Output should be `NA NA NA 2004-02 NA 2006-03 2007-07 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what the post wants as an output, but might not cover all the edge cases required.

```
vt = c("2004-02","2006-03","2007-07")
vv <- rep(NA_character_, 18)
ids <- as.integer(substr(vt, 4, 4))
vv[ids] <- vt
vv
```

However, note that this depends on unique years being provided, overwriting the last occurrence. That is,

```
vt = c("2004-02","2006-03","2007-07", "2007-01")
```

Will give somewhat misleading results. Another note: The year 2000 will throw an error. If there are such cases, `as.integer(substr(vt, 4, 4)) + 1` could be used (on a length 19 vector).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Data start with the year 2002 and the year does not repeat, so this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
vt <- c("2004-02","2006-03","2007-07")
vv <- rep(NA, 18)

vv[as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(vt, "-"), `[`, 1))-2000] <- vt
```